# Conceptual problems with BEM and nesting

Tags: html, css, bem

I'm trying to adapt some HTML/CSS code to the BEM methodology but seeing the classes for the HTML I think I'm doing something wrong.

I have a nested object "footer__social" with some nested icons. Following the FAQ's advice in the official BEM page I end up with a HTML code like that:

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer__logo"></div>
  <div class="footer__social">
    <div class="footer__facebook"></div>
    <div class="footer__twitter"></div>
    <div class="footer__pinterest"></div>
    <div class="footer__googleplus"></div>
    <div class="footer__linkedin"></div>
    <div class="footer__youtube"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="footer__copyright">2016 todos los derechos reservados</p>
  <p class="footer__policy">Política de privacidad</p>
  <p class="footer__terms">Términos y condiciones</p>
</footer>
```

Here is the link to the FAQ: https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-does-bem-not-recommend-using-elements-within-elements-block__elem1__elem2

To me it feels really strange to have the "footer__" in each of the HTML tags.

The idea I have is to rename the "footer__social" and start a BEM block renaming it to "social" with their children renamed to "social__facebook", etc... but feel that the "social" block is disconnected from the footer (it only appears there).

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer__logo"></div>
  <div class="social">
    <div class="social__facebook"></div>
    <div class="social__twitter"></div>
    <div class="social__pinterest"></div>
    <div class="social__googleplus"></div>
    <div class="social__linkedin"></div>
    <div class="social__youtube"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="footer__copyright">2016 todos los derechos reservados</p>
  <p class="footer__policy">Política de privacidad</p>
  <p class="footer__terms">Términos y condiciones</p>
</footer>
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: The key is to not mix up context specific styling and general component styling. If you need to style the `social` component specifically for how it displays inside of `footer` IMO it should either be defined as you described in the first scenario or have `class="footer__social social"` to allow for separation. ( That being said I'm not a BEM purist ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples are both correct!

Without knowing more context about the styles and the implementation idea, it will be hard to say which is the best approach.

If we say:

1. The "social" block is connected with the footer explicitly;
2. It only appears and will appear there;
3. You want to **emphasize the fact that it is connected with the footer**.

Then, **go with the `footer__` prefix**. That makes the most sense to me:

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer__logo"></div>
  <div class="footer__social">
    <div class="footer__facebook"></div>
    <div class="footer__twitter"></div>
    <div class="footer__pinterest"></div>
    <div class="footer__googleplus"></div>
    <div class="footer__linkedin"></div>
    <div class="footer__youtube"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="footer__copyright">2016 todos los derechos reservados</p>
  <p class="footer__policy">Política de privacidad</p>
  <p class="footer__terms">Términos y condiciones</p>
</footer>
```

If it still doesn't *feel right* to you, based on my experience, often times strictly following the BEM naming techniques doesn't always *feel right*. There are a few great resources, that guided me towards this process, so I recommend you to check the following two:

- http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/ by Harry Roberts
- http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-html-semantics-front-end-architecture/ by Nicolas Gallagher

PS: For all these additional suggestions and ideas, it is important to note:

> Whatever the actual notation used, they are all based on the same BEM principles.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are perfectly valid. But your second example is more modular where your social component can easily be moved to another location that way. Styling your social component should be independent from your footer as well.

Regarding the rest of the markup maybe you dont need all these classes but just a container, for example like this:

```
<div class="footer__info">
    <p>2016 todos los derechos reservados</p>
    <p>Política de privacidad</p>
    <p>Términos y condiciones</p>
</div>
```